# Download File from Server with Blazor App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have created an `HttpGet` in my Server-API which creates a CSV-File and returns it with `FileStreamResult`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
    // do logic to create csv in memoryStream

    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "text/csv;charset=utf-8") {
        FileDownloadName = "products.csv",
    };
}
```

In my Blazor-Client App, I have created a Button with a handler:

```cs
private async Task DownloadCatalog() {
    var file = HttpClient.GetAsync("api/csvProduct");

    // ... how do I download the file in the browser?
}
```

The Get in the Controller is called, but I don't know what to do so that the file is downloaded in the browser after the api call.

Comment: did some search, you can either **invoke** javascript or `Navigation.NavigateTo(the api endpoint teturning File)`

Comment: complete coded example in .NET 5 based on accepted answer:   https://github.com/tysongibby/BlazorExcelFileDownload

Comment: @TysonGibby What's the currently there (commit  8242e35) doesn't compile.  You have to go back on version back.

Comment: @zumalifeguard This has been fixed.  I had stopped mid-update and forgot to finish it. It is now also based on .NET 6.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Browsers don't allow scripts to write to the file system, whether written in JavaScript or WebAssembly. The download dialog is displayed by the browser only when the user clicks on a link.

**Using a link button**

If the final file is returned directly from the server, the easiest solution is to use a link button with a URL to the API endpoint, possibly calculated at runtime. You can use the `download` attribute to specify a file name. When the user clicks on the link, the file will be retrieved and saved using the `download` name

For example :

```
<a id="exportCsv" class="btn" href="api/csvProduct" download="MyFile.csv" 
   role="button" target="=_top">Export to CSV</a>
```

or

```
@if (_exportUrl != null)
{
    <a id="exportCsv" class="btn" href="@_exportUrl" download="MyFile.csv" 
       role="button" target="=_top">Export to Csv</a>
}

...
int _productId=0;
string? _exportUrl=null;

async Task Search()
{
   //Get and display a product summary
   _model=await GetProductSummary(_productId);
   //Activate the download URL 
   _exportUrl = $"api/csvProduct/{_productId}";
}
```

**Using a dynamically generated data link**

If that's not possible, you have to create a link element in JavaScript with a data URL, or a Blob, and click it. That's SLOOOOW for three reasons :

1. You're making an in-memory copy of the downloaded file that's at least 33% larger than the original.
2. JS interop data marshalling is *slow*, which means that passing the bytes from Blazor to Javascript is also slow.
3. Byte arrays are passed as Base64 strings. These need to be decoded back into a byte array to be used as blobs.

The article [Generating and efficiently exporting a file in a Blazor WebAssembly application](https://www.meziantou.net/generating-and-downloading-a-file-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm) shows how to pass the bytes *without* marshaling using some Blazor runtime tricks.

If you use Blazor WASM, you can use use `InvokeUnmarshalled` to pass a `byte[]` array and have it appear as a `Uint8Array` in JavaScript.

```
    byte[] file = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Cast<byte>().ToArray();
    string fileName = "file.bin";
    string contentType = "application/octet-stream";

    // Check if the IJSRuntime is the WebAssembly implementation of the JSRuntime
    if (JSRuntime is IJSUnmarshalledRuntime webAssemblyJSRuntime)
    {
        webAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeUnmarshalled<string, string, byte[], bool>("BlazorDownloadFileFast", fileName, contentType, file);
    }
    else
    {
        // Fall back to the slow method if not in WebAssembly
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorDownloadFile", fileName, contentType, file);
    }
```

The `BlazorDownloadFileFast` JavaScript method retrieves the array, converts it to a File and then, through `URL.createObjectURL` to a safe data URL that can be clicked :

```
function BlazorDownloadFileFast(name, contentType, content) {
    // Convert the parameters to actual JS types
    const nameStr = BINDING.conv_string(name);
    const contentTypeStr = BINDING.conv_string(contentType);
    const contentArray = Blazor.platform.toUint8Array(content);

    // Create the URL
    const file = new File([contentArray], nameStr, { type: contentTypeStr });
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Create the <a> element and click on it
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = exportUrl;
    a.download = nameStr;
    a.target = "_self";
    a.click();

    // We don't need to keep the url, let's release the memory
    // On Safari it seems you need to comment this line... (please let me know if you know why)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
    a.remove();
}
```

With Blazor Server, marshaling is unavoidable. In this case the slower `BlazorDownloadFile` method is called. The `byte[]` array is marshaled as a BASE64 string which has to be decoded. Unfortunately, JavaScript's `atob` and `btoa` functions [can't handle every value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) so we need another method to decode Base64 into Uint8Array:

```
function BlazorDownloadFile(filename, contentType, content) {
    // Blazor marshall byte[] to a base64 string, so we first need to convert the string (content) to a Uint8Array to create the File
    const data = base64DecToArr(content);

    // Create the URL
    const file = new File([data], filename, { type: contentType });
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Create the <a> element and click on it
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = exportUrl;
    a.download = filename;
    a.target = "_self";
    a.click();

    // We don't need to keep the url, let's release the memory
    // On Safari it seems you need to comment this line... (please let me know if you know why)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
    a.remove();
}
```

And the decoder function, borrowed from Mozilla's [Base64 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)

```
// Convert a base64 string to a Uint8Array. This is needed to create a blob object from the base64 string.
// The code comes from: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/D%C3%A9coder_encoder_en_base64
function b64ToUint6(nChr) {
  return nChr > 64 && nChr < 91 ? nChr - 65 : nChr > 96 && nChr < 123 ? nChr - 71 : nChr > 47 && nChr < 58 ? nChr + 4 : nChr === 43 ? 62 : nChr === 47 ? 63 : 0;
}

function base64DecToArr(sBase64, nBlocksSize) {
  var
    sB64Enc = sBase64.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g, ""),
    nInLen = sB64Enc.length,
    nOutLen = nBlocksSize ? Math.ceil((nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2) / nBlocksSize) * nBlocksSize : nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2,
    taBytes = new Uint8Array(nOutLen);

  for (var nMod3, nMod4, nUint24 = 0, nOutIdx = 0, nInIdx = 0; nInIdx < nInLen; nInIdx++) {
    nMod4 = nInIdx & 3;
    nUint24 |= b64ToUint6(sB64Enc.charCodeAt(nInIdx)) << 18 - 6 * nMod4;
    if (nMod4 === 3 || nInLen - nInIdx === 1) {
      for (nMod3 = 0; nMod3 < 3 && nOutIdx < nOutLen; nMod3++, nOutIdx++) {
        taBytes[nOutIdx] = nUint24 >>> (16 >>> nMod3 & 24) & 255;
      }
      nUint24 = 0;
    }
  }
  return taBytes;
}
```

**Blazor 6**

The [ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-6/#efficient-byte-array-transfer-in-javascript-interop) that was released recently no longer marshals `byte[]` as a Base64 string. It should be possible to use the following function

```
function BlazorDownloadFile(filename, contentType, data) {

    // Create the URL
    const file = new File([data], filename, { type: contentType });
    const exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Create the <a> element and click on it
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = exportUrl;
    a.download = filename;
    a.target = "_self";
    a.click();

    // We don't need to keep the url, let's release the memory
    // On Safari it seems you need to comment this line... (please let me know if you know why)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
    a.remove();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify this code so that the file is opened for viewing instead of downloaded? So, if the file happens to be an image, it is opened in the user's default image viewer, and if it is an XML, it is opened in the default browser (or another app depending on the settings), etc.?

Comment: This is genius.. Must be the _top or role=button... saved me from doing all that nastiness you posted above

Comment: @TimDavis I didn't invent this and the code is still nasty. There's a [draft File System API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) but few browsers support it yet. [showSaveFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker) is supported only on recent Chrome and Edge versions

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, especially the excellent update for .NET 6

Comment: I would just recommend to `a.remove();` after the file is downloaded, just for house keeping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but when I don't remove the `a` element, the element remains in the DOM with an invalid url to the removed object.

Comment: This is much faster than the [Microsoft Recommended Way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0) of doing it.  Kudos!

Comment: @Mmm the basic technique is the same. If you check the code, all snippets pass the bytes to Javascript which then creates a blob, then a data URL and clicks it. The unmarshalled trick was written by meziantou, not me. The only question is how to pass the data without double/triple-buffering. The MS article works for both WASM and Server and uses the *newer* stream support to pass the data from server to browser without converting it to BASE64. For large files read from disk this will be better than loading the entire file in memory, then sending it to the browser

Comment: @Mmm imagine you have a *server*-generated PDF or Excel file for example. It's a lot better to open a stream on that file and "send" the stream to the browser than buffering the entire file in memory and then .... have ASP.NET Core buffer the response again if you're not careful. PS: in the MS example the MemoryStream is used as a mock for a file stream in the `GetFileStream()` method. They explain that in the paragraph above the method

Comment: The technique may be the same, however the MS version is significantly slower from my experience.

Comment: Any idea how to overcome the size limitation of byte array ? Can export records up to 1.5 lakh records , but trying to export more records no actions occuring

Comment: Don't use such a blob to begin with. Browsers don't like big blobs. Use a download link. Until browsers (and Blazor) allow saving to a local file, the only way to trigger a save is to dynamically construct a download link. That means the same data ends up cached on the browser multiple times - in Blazor *and* the JS object URL at least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is it the approach using Link Button on this answer?

Comment: It's the very first one. If preparing the file takes a long time you could start with a hidden link and display it to the user, perhaps even in a Modal, when the file preparation is done.

Comment: complete coded example in .NET 5:   https://github.com/tysongibby/BlazorExcelFileDownload

Answer (score 12):

In order to download file you have to use Microsoft JSInterop. There are many ways to implement your request. One way that i use, is to get the file as byte array then convert it to base64string. Finally call the function that you created in javascript.

In server side

```
js.InvokeVoidAsync("jsSaveAsFile",
                        filename,
                        Convert.ToBase64String(GetFileByteArrayFunction())
                        );
```

And in javascript file in wwwroot you create a function

```
function jsSaveAsFile(filename, byteBase64) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = filename;
link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + byteBase64;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);}
```

Comment: thank you, this works very good.  Small note: this only worked for me when I placed this code inside the @code {  }  section on the razor page. It did not work when placed in the code behind.

Comment: The function jsSaveAsFile is placed on <scritps> section and it is called on Index.html It is not necessary  to call it from code section, it is up to you. I call it from class where i generate the file.

Answer (score 2):

use the NavigationManager

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

private async Task DownloadCatalog() {
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("api/csvProduct",true);
}
```

Comment: But what to do when the document opens in a new tab, when I want it downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `HttpClient.GetAsync` the Blazor runtime gets the file. But it cannot directly save the file to the disk as a Browser environment (in which Blazor runs) does not have access to the disk.

So you will have to use some Javascript Interop to trigger the file download feature of the browser. You can generate a link `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,<<content of the file>>` and invoke click on it.

Comment: This is limited to the 2k URL length so not as useful as it may seem.