# Blazor (Wasm) with ReportViewer export

Tags: blazor, rdlc, reportviewer, webassembly

I am following the instructions on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7V0Yb5drLgQ

When the link is put directly into my razor's component html section everything works:

**RazorComponent**

```
<a type="button" style="margin-left:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="https://localhost:5001/api/Report/GetReport?reportType=1">
        <span class="oi oi-data-transfer-download"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;@(l.Keys["CPVH_Download_PDF"])
    </a>
</div>
```

And below is my API's controller logic

**Server Api**

```
   [HttpGet("[action]/{reportType}")]
    public IActionResult GetReport(int reportType)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt = employeeService.GetEmployee();

        string mimeType = "";
        int extension = 1;
        var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report1.rdlc";

        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameters.Add("param", "RDLC report in Blazor Web Assembly");

        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
        
        localReport.AddDataSource("dsEmployee", dt);

        //For Pdf
        if (reportType == 1)
        {
            var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimeType);
            return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf", "myPdf.pdf");
        }
        else //if (reportType == 1)
        {
            //For Excel
            var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Excel, extension, parameters, mimeType);
            return File(result.MainStream, "application/msexcel", "myReport.xls");
        }
    }
```

However, when I wrap the razor component call into a service invoking a Get or a Post eventhough I still hit the controller the file does not get downloaded. I only get an Ok reponse but no file download happening.

**Service Invoking the call to the api**

```
  public async Task GetReport(int reportType)
    {
        var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString()}/Report/GetReport/{reportType}");

        var saveDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "myPdf.pdf");

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            File.WriteAllBytes(saveDir, content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what the code is trying to do. The Razor component contains just a link. Clicking on it navigates to its URL. There's nothing to wrap. A file is downloaded only because the controller returns a binary file.  You could perform the same thing by writing `var bytes=await HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/Report/GetReport?reportType=1")`. If you specify that the HttpClient's base address is `https://localhost:5001/api/Report/GetReport?reportType=1` you can use `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("GetReport?reportType=1")`.

Comment: Excel or PDF files are *not* text, so you can't use `Content.ReadAsStringAsync` to read them. You'll have to use `ReadAsByteArrayAsync` or `ReadAsStreamAsync`

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your help! I have reviewed your comments and have made a slight change onto my code under the section "Service Invoking the call to the api". To answer your questions I am trying to call the api and get the  report bytes and save them onto a file in the blazor client.  As for the wrapping into a service part of your question, currently I have left it as a plain simple service but more code will be added eventually including model parameters but currently I am not doing this. The problem I am still facing is no file gets generated into the disc...

Comment: Further more if i do _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync I cannot then use httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result
This only works if if do GetAsync as GetByteArrayAsync result does not have a content property.

Comment: The reason I want the wrapping instead of plain simple link is that eventually I would want to pass more data to the controller.

Comment: I ve found an answer stating it is not possible to do what I am trying to do, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393235/download-file-from-server-with-blazor-app for more information.

Comment: Check who wrote it. Yes, you can download files in Blazor. I wrote how you can do this.  But that's *not* what you asked. Unless `Service Invoking the call to the api` actually means `Blazor code trying to save the file to the end user's disk`

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your help, yes indeed its you, I have upvoted your answers. `Service Invoking the call to the api` is so that I could do more withing the ivnoke method like add additional params and follow our implementation standards where api calls are available through services only. All this worked correctly until i tried to `Blazor code trying to save the file to the end user's disk` where everything stops. And no file gets generated client side.

Comment: Browsers don't allow client code to access the file system *yet*.  There's a very early version of a [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) available only on Chrome and Edge v86 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I 've found how to solve this issue using a third party extension: https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorDownloadFile

_iBlazorDownloadFileService.DownloadFile gets the fileBytes and turns them to a file saved in the Downloads folder.

Here my implementation

**Service**

```
 public async Task<byte[]> GetReport(int reportType)
 {
    var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString()}/Report/GetReport/{reportType}");
    byte[] content = null;

    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        content = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

    return content;
 }
```

**Razor.component**

```
@inject IExportService _iExportService
@inject IBlazorDownloadFileService  _iBlazorDownloadFileService 
      
<a style="margin-left:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @onclick="@(async ()=> await GetExport((int)ExportTypesEnum.Pdf))"  >
            <span class="oi oi-data-transfer-download"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;@(l.Keys["CPVH_Download_PDF"])
        </a>
@code {
    public async Task GetExport(int reportType)
    {
        var fileBytes = await _iExportService.GetReport(reportType);
                
        await _iBlazorDownloadFileService.DownloadFile("myPdf.pdf", fileBytes, "application/pdf");

    }
}
```

Comment: That extension does nothing more than what's shown in every question that asks how to download a file in Javascript - pass a byte array to a Javascript function, create a blob, then a data URL from it and click the URL. It doesn't take advantage of fast marshalling or streams in Blazor 6 though. The actual process is described in the Blazor docs, in [ASP.NET Core Blazor file downloads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It would be faster if you used `http.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` and passed the stream to `downloadFileFromStream`

Comment: BTW if you want to make a call relative to HttpClient's base address, you don't need to repeat it. You could write just `await _httpClient.GetAsync($"Report/GetReport/{reportType}");`