# Download File from Blazor Server without Separate Download Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to download a file from a Blazor server app. The file is created in the same .razor file that I want the button to be. I have seen a method for downloading a file using a link to another page, but is there a way to download a file without exposing the download through a separate page?

I referenced the following two links to create a workaround, but it feels like a hack.

[Download File from Server with Blazor App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393235/download-file-from-server-with-blazor-app)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/243420/blazor-server-app-downlaod-files-from-server.html

**Current Solution**: Create a Blazor page with DownloadMyFile.cshtml and DownloadMyFile.cshtml.cs. Add a button to OtherPage.razor to link to DownloadMyFile.

*DownloadMyFile.cshtml*

```
@page "/downloadMyFile"
@model BudgetingApp.Pages.DownloadMyFile
```

*DownloadMyFile.cshtml.cs*

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace BudgetingApp.Pages
{
    public class DownloadMyFile : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

        public DownloadMyFile(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "myFile.txt");
            var fileInBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            return File(fileInBytes, "application/force-download", "myFile.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

*OtherPage.razor*

```
<a class="form-control btn btn-primary" href="/downloadMyFile">Download</a>
```

*and elsewhere in OtherPage.razor*

```
<button @onclick="CreateFile">Create File</button>

...

private void CreateFile()
{
    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "myFile.txt")))
            {
            }
}
```

**Desired Improvement**: Ideally I want a button in OtherPage.razor that will create myFile.txt at wwwroot and trigger the download. Short of that, I would like a button (or link) that will download myFile.txt without me needing to create DownloadMyFile.cshtml and DownloadMyFile.cshtml.cs

Comment: You need an endpoint that returns the content. But it looks like the `.UseStaticFiles();` middleware is what you actually want here. Unless you want to stream generated content directly to `Response.Body`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? The OnGet method returns the content. Do I need to move it to a publically accessible enpoint?