# System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(destinationPath, bytes) is not creating image file on Local Drive

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am uploading a file using MudFileUpload in Blazor WebAssembly Project using Mudblazor Nuget package. Picture is displayed well in  tag, but is not saved on my local drive. Please see the code both for razor page and razor.cs file:

```
<MudFileUpload T="IBrowserFile" FilesChanged="UploadFiles">
    <ButtonTemplate>
        <MudFab HtmlTag="label"
            Color="Color.Secondary"
            Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Image"
            Label="Load picture"
            for="@context" />
    </ButtonTemplate>
</MudFileUpload>
<img src="@profilePicDataUrl" style="width:250px; height:250px;" />

public async Task UploadFiles(IBrowserFile file)
{
    string imageBase64 = string.Empty;
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    await using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    await file.OpenReadStream(file.Size).CopyToAsync(fs);
    var bytes = new byte[file.Size];
    fs.Position = 0;
    await fs.ReadAsync(bytes);
    fs.Close();
    File.Delete(path);
    profilePicDataUrl = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}";
    string destinationFileName = "Destination.jpg";
    var destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("E:\\Test\\", 
    destinationFileName).Replace("/",string.Empty);
    await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(destinationPath, bytes);
}
```

I have replaced "/" with string.Empty because during debugging I found destinationPath as "E:\Test/Destination.jpg".
During debugging I can see all the code runs well not exception or error occurred, but no file is created on specified Test folder. Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File from Server with Blazor App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393235/download-file-from-server-with-blazor-app). You do not have access to the file system when your running on the client side within a browser.

Comment: "not exception or error occurred"  Is because you wrote to an in-memory file system. Follow the linked dupe.

Comment: @Mushroomator. thanks