# How to Prompt the User to Choose a PDF File Storage Location in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I'm working on a Blazor application and using the QuestPDF library to generate PDFs. I want to provide a feature where, when the user clicks a button, they can choose the location where the generated PDF file will be stored. I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this in Blazor using QuestPDF.

When the user clicks a specific button, I want to trigger a file dialog that allows the user to select the directory or location where the PDF file should be saved.

1. How can I show a file dialog in a Blazor application to let the user choose the directory for PDF file storage?
2. Are there any specific Blazor or QuestPDF features or functions that can assist in this process?

Any help, advice, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what Blazor is / does.  At the end point, it's just HTML rendered in a browser.  If you want to input a file, you use a file input.  Yes, there's a Blazor tag with some parameters you can set, but when you load your page and inspect it in Chrome dev tools, it's html.  My point is this: google "How to open a file in html" first, then figure out if there's a Blazor-specific way of handling the file upload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File from Server with Blazor App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393235/download-file-from-server-with-blazor-app)

Comment: You can't control where the browser saves files *yet*. There's a File System API that's only supported by Desktop versions of Chrome and Edge. The common way used in all SPAs is to use an anchor with a download attribute eg  `<a class="btn" href="api/generateReport" download="MyReport.pdf">...`. That anchor can be created dynamically too with a data URL, ie a ULR that contains the BASE64-encoded contents of the file. That's used to save responses from API calls that can't be converted to anchors

Comment: I just found out that it was a limitation, as what @PanagiotisKanavos said. Thank you everyone for the insightful response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Filesystem API - it is not available on all browsers.

The easiest way to use it is with https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess

[Demo](https://kristofferstrube.github.io/Blazor.FileSystemAccess/SaveFile)

```cs
    protected async Task OpenFilePickerAndSave()
    {
        try
        {
            FileHandle = await FileSystemAccessService.ShowSaveFilePickerAsync();
        }
        catch (JSException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        if (FileHandle is not null)
        {
            var writable = await FileHandle.CreateWritableAsync();
            await writable.WriteAsync(pdfData);
            await writable.CloseAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is [only supported in Chrome and Edge desktop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showOpenFilePicker), so its usefulness is limited.

Comment: It does say right at the top "it is not available on all browsers"