# Download varbinary data from SQL Server table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm new to web development and Blazor in particular. I'm developing â Blazor server-side app using Entity Framework Core and SQL Server database as backend.

I was able to add / edit / delete fields in the tables but didn't find any good / simple example how to download and upload data from / to a `varbinary` column.

The working examples I found were using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` but it is deprecated. The table with `varbinary` data is shown here:

[Companies table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrjDu.png)

I've tried many versions of the code but they didn't work

```
public async Task DownloadFile(int id = 0)
{
    using var dbContext = _context;

    var company = await dbContext.Companies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            
    if (company == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    byte[] fileData = company.CompanyDocs;
    var filename = "YourDesiredFilename.pdf"; 
    File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\dd.xlsx", fileData);
}
```

This code in my service class gets the `varbinary` data, but it is completely incorrect and definitely not the original file uploaded to the database.

What is expected: the user clicks the "Download" link to download the file, and it is saved to his PC like any ordinary download.

Comment: Don't use an ORM like EF if you only want to return a single value in the first place. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection. There aren't any objects involved here

Comment: EF and ASP.Net are irrelevant here. In fact you're asking how to download data using blazor: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68393235/861716

Comment: Gert, but how to adjust the code from this page stackoverflow.com/q/68393235/861716  to work with sql server binary field?

Comment: The code presented should function correctly. Are you sure the upload function is putting the correct data in the DB?

Comment: Yes, the input is done using desktop app and it is a file that is 150 KB (excel).  by using the code above I get 15 MB binary data that is not usable. and it does not trigger browser dowload. just scilently saves to the directory sprecified.